# Visual Studio Code does showing GUI in Win 7

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have recently faced the issue in Visual Studio Code, whenever I am trying to launch the "Application", it is showing nothing but a black screen.
Previously it was working, but after installation of ".NET Framework" (for "MySQL" server requisite), the problem started.
I have re-installed Visual Studio Code but the issue is the same.
It was perfectly working before ".NET framework".
Is this because of ".NET framework" or something else?[image][image]
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urMNh.jpg)

Comment: .NET Framework should already have been installed when you installed Visual Studio Code. Why did you need to install it again? It's possible your new installation of it has been corrupted

Comment: @UnholySheep VS _Code_ is platform independent, so it doesn't automatically install the old .NET 4.x framework. You may have mixed the full Visual Studio IDE with the Visual Studio _Code_ text editor.

Comment: @Lion The official documentation clearly states that VSCode require .NET Framework 4.5.2 to run on Windows: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/requirements

Comment: Try to install previous version. Had similar thing with Raspberry PI. Helped installing previous version.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm sorry, you're right. I mainly use VS code on Linux and less frequently VS IDE on Windows. So I'm wondering that the old .NET 4.x is really required since its an platform independent Electron application. Don't know what MS did there, seems to be not completely build on native technology, at least for Windows.

Comment: I have tried with code --disable-gpu, it was working but it's only temporary.